# Summing each play of a player in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas df as below where the scores of two players are tabulated. I want to calculate the *sum of each game* of each player where each game is scored consecutively. For example the first game played by A has a total score of 12, the second game played by A has a total score of 10, the first game played by B has a total score of 4 etc. How can I do this pandas way (vectorised or groupby etc) please?

`df_players.groupby("Player").sum("Score")`
does only give overall total score and not for each game individually.

Many thanks.

| Player | Score |
| --- | --- |
| A | 10 |
| A | 2 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 3 |
| A | 3 |
| A | 7 |
| B | 2 |

Comment: How do you know when a game *starts* and when it *ends*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an island-and-gap problem. Whenever the Player changes, a new island is formed.

```py
# Build the islands. If the current row's Player is not equal to the previous
# row's Player, create a new island. We don't care about the island number, only
# that rows with consecutive Player are assigned to the same island.
island = df["Player"].ne(df["Player"].shift()).cumsum().rename("Island")

result = (
    # One Player + one Island = one Game
    df.groupby([df["Player"], island]).sum()
    # Now, for each Player, label the Games consecutively 
    .assign(Game=lambda x: x.groupby("Player").cumcount() + 1)
    .set_index("Game", append=True)
)
```

Result:

```
                    Score
Player Island Game       
A      1      1        12
       3      2        10
B      2      1         4
       4      2         2
```

Comment: This code looks like a Van Gogh masterpiece. Fantastic. Thank you @Code-Different

Answer (score 0):

You don't have Game in your DataFrame ... I assume the first two scores in your table are for Player A in Game #1 but I'm just guessing that since you said you expected the result to be 12.  There is no way to figure this out from the data you provided.  Add a column for Game to the DataFrame and then group by player and game ... the by= parameter of groupby() can take a list of columns to group by.

Comment: When the player changes in player column the game changes hands. Sorry if the earlier question was not very clear. So for instance A scores 10 and 2 in Game 1, while B scores 1 and 3 in Game 1. But the number of games each play is not fixed so A can have a go for 10 rows and B can perhaps only have 3 rows. In the player column when A changes to B it means A's that particular game is finished and B starts his/her game etc. I can do this in a non-vectorised clumsy way but wanted to know if there is an elegant pandas solution. Thank you.

Comment: No, there is no way to do this.  Your description above assumes some 'natural order' for a DF and there is none. 
If the index on the DF is a RangeIndex, i.e. a monotonic integer index, and tells you who's turn it was, such that A gets 2 turns and B gets 2 turns and then the game ends: in that case just use a mod operator to translate from Turn# into Game#. But realize what you are doing is mapping from Turn# to Game#.  But if no such many-to-one logical mapping exists then in reality, then there is no way to do what you want.

Comment: It may be helpful to think about it like this --  if someone did a `df.sort_values(by=['Player']) ` on your DataFrame then it would be an identical DataFrame but you would have no idea what rows correspond to what games. If that's the case then you are missing the information necessary to perform any operation requiring Game# as an operand.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `cumsum()` for `cumulative_sum`.

```py
df_players.groupby('Player').cumsum()
```

You can add this as a new column to the existing frame like:

```py
df_players['Running Score'] = df_players.groupby('Player').cumsum()
```

Comment: Thanks @scotscotmcc. I thought of cumsum but it is only a visual solution. Is there a way to list each game of A and B its total score .